# Java subprocess dying when JVM shuts down

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I have a bash file called **update.sh** which essentially

1. pulls the latest code from github
2. compiles the new code
3. stops the running java server
4. starts the java server again using the updated code

My java code is as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/root/update.sh");
```

The problem is that when step #3 of update.sh is run, it is killing the JVM, which in turn is killing the subprocess which is running update.sh, meaning that it never makes it to step 4.

Is there a way to make it so that java can spawn a subprocess that persists even after the JVM shuts down?

I'm using an EC2 Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways could be decoupling the part that runs update.sh and the java server from each other and making a separate unix process for updating the server. You can make the updating process even survive possible restarts wrapping it in a [upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart_(software)) script

UPDATE: or [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), or [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), or [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), etc. (thanks  @charles-duffy)

Comment: ...upstart, or runit, or daemontools, or systemd, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful for someone -- I solved this by having my script restart the server using "nohup"

```
nohup restart.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: `nohup` does nothing that bash can't do itself using only builtin functionality.

Comment: `./restart.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null </dev/null & disown -h` -- `disown -h` tells the shell to not forward HUP signals to the job in question, and everything there is built into bash itself, vs `nohup` which needs to be separately installed and adds extra execution overhead. Note that it may well have been the FIFO from stdin dying that killed your process (sending it a `SIGPIPE`), rather than the `HUP` signal; one of the side effects of `nohup` is that it redirects all three of stdin/stdout/stderr, just as the above example does explicitly.

Comment: I didn't install nohup separately, it seemed to just work out of the box

Comment: Some OS vendors preinstall it, but you're limiting portability to those platforms. (Granted, the other way, you're limiting portability to platforms with bash, so there are constraints either way).

Answer (score -2):

Why you are not using a prebuilt application to manage this job for you?
For example, Jenkins is one of the best apps that will do all you need also you can connect to any 3rd party to have better management like slack to send the messages to control if it was a success build or not.